# Using Wordpress PCL I always get 401 rest_cannot_access

Tags: wordpress-rest-api

I want to access Wordpress REST-API from C# using [WordpressPCL](https://github.com/wp-net/WordPressPCL).
Therefore I installed the Wordpress Plugin "JWT Authentication for WP-API" and configured .htaccess and wp-config.php as mentioned in the plugin documentation.
But I always get

```
{"code":"rest_cannot_access","message":"Nur authorisierte Benutzer k\u00f6nnen auf die REST API zugreifen.","data":{"status":401}}
```

when trying to request a token with correct username and password.
I tried different installations of WP - on Linux and Windows.

What is the cause of this problem? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case it was an additional plugin called "Password Protected". This one forced a cookie authentication for every call to the wordpress instance. Even for calls to wp-json. After deactivating the plugin, the problem had disappeared.